# Python script with decimal comparisation and output

Tags: python

I have a text files with filename such as "randomname.out".
I need to read 4th, 5th and 6th line from each file which contains numbers delimited with space or tab.
From the read input line I need to check wether the last decimal number (last delimited field) is less than zero. If it is not, it should proceed to another file. If it is less than 0.000, it should create or append a file called "results.txt" with the filename followed by the comma and the decimal.

the result.txt output should be like this:

```
randomname.out,result_from_4th_line,result_from_5th_line,result_from_6th_line
anotherrandomname.out,result_from_4th_line,result_from_5th_line,result_from_6th_line
```

eg:

```
randomname.out,-7.22,-2.199,-1.99
randomothername.out,-6.0,-5.912,-0.05
```

How to do this? Asking because I cannot do it with bash and I have no experience whatsoever with python. This is my first time ever. Cannot install ksh (only bash installed) which could do it easily, but the server has python.

This is what I have mustered up but it doesn't work as supposed.

```
import glob, os, csv
def printout():
    hs=open("result.txt","a")
    if(os.path.getsize("result.txt") > 0):
        hs.write("\n"+file+","+lastcolumn)
    else:
        hs.write(file+","+lastcolumn)
    hs.close()


for file in glob.glob('*.out'):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 4 and i == 5 and i == 6:
            last_column = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')]  
            if last_column < 0:
                    printout()
```

Comment: You have multiple indentation problems and a function in the middle of the loop that doesn't return anything or ever get called (as well as useless `elif` statements). You have to go back to the basics of python syntax

Comment: I'd rather get this working and never use python again. This is not my homework but I needed to get this thing done couple days ago, I really do not have any motivation to learn python. Hence I am asking the spoonfeeding here. I have never ever written any code with python before. Anyway, I edited the code, but it doesn't help

Comment: Well, could you please tell me what I should do next :P